# How to integrate Flow type with Ant Design form?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, antd

I'm using Ant Design's Form as a wrapper around my component `FormComponent`. However this wrapping negates Flow's check that I always pass in the required props to `FormComponent`.

```
    import { Form } from "antd"

    type Props = {|
      userID: string,
      form: Form,
    |};

    class FormComponent extends Component<Props> {
        ...
    }

    export default Form.create()(FormComponent);
```

Normally, if I were to invoke `<FormComponent />` in another file without passing in any props, Flow would throw an error. However, it seems that the `Form.create()` wrapping blocks this error check. How do I get it back? I've tried `Form.create<Props>()(FormComponent)`, which didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing it like this and it is kind of working:

```
import type { FormProps } from 'antd';
import { Form } from 'antd';

type OwnProps = {|
  userID: string,
|};

type Props = OwnProps & FormProps;

class FormComponent extends Component<Props> {
  ...
}

export default Form.create()(FormComponent);
```

The only thing that is driving me nuts is that the `form` prop is optional in `FormProps` and flow wants me to check if `typeof this.props.form !== 'undefined'` before accessing something like `validateFields()`.

Has anyone found a better solution than this one?